# Unit test using the Reflections google library fails only when executed by Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, classloader, maven-3, reflections

I am using the Google [Reflections library](http://code.google.com/p/reflections/) for querying certain resources in the classpath. Those resources are located in the same location than the classes in my project.

I wrote some unit tests that succeed when executed as a unit test in Eclipse, but when I try to execute them with Maven (with a `maven install` for example), they are not working as expected. 
After some debugging, apparently the problem is that when executed with Maven, the Reflections library cannot find the classpath url where the resources are located.

I arrived to that conclusion researching how Reflections determines the classpath URLs that should be inspected. As an example, the following method shows how Reflections finds the available classpath URLs given a class loader (the original Reflections method has been simplified a bit):

```
public static Set<URL> forClassLoader(ClassLoader... classLoaders) {
    final Set<URL> result = Sets.newHashSet();
    for (ClassLoader classLoader : classLoaders) {
        while (classLoader != null) {
            if (classLoader instanceof URLClassLoader) {
                URL[] urls = ((URLClassLoader) classLoader).getURLs();
                if (urls != null) {
                    result.addAll(Sets.<URL>newHashSet(urls));
                }
            } 
            classLoader = classLoader.getParent();
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

In short, it is traversing the class loader hierarchy asking for the URLs of each individual classloader.

When in Eclipse I invoke the previous method from a unit test with something like this:

```
    ClassLoader myClassClassLoader = <MyClass>.class.getClassLoader(); //<MyClass> is in the same classpath url than the resources I need to find
    Set<URL> urls = forClassLoader(myClassClassLoader);
    for(URL url : urls) {
      System.out.println("a url: " + url);
```

as expected, I can see (among many other URLs) the classpath URLs that are configured as part of my project:

```
file:<MY_PROJECT_PATH>/target/classes/
file:<MY_PROJECT_PATH>/target/test-classes/
```

and Reflections works as a charm (the resources Reflections should find are located in `file:<MY_PROJECT_PATH>/target/classes/`).

However, when the test is executed by Maven, I realized that these URL entries are missing from the set returned by the `forClassLoader` method, and the rest of the Reflections methods are not working as expected for this problem.

The "surprising" thing is that if I write this when the unit test is executed by maven:

```
ClassLoader myClassClassLoader = <MyClass>.class.getClassLoader();
url = myClassClassLoader.getResource("anExistingResource");
System.out.println("URL: "+url); //a valid URL
```

I can see that the class loader still can resolve the resource I am trying to find. 
I am puzzled about why when executed with Maven the `forClassLoader` method does not include in the returned set the classpath URLs of my project, although at the same time it is able to resolve resources that are located in such urls(!).

What is the reason of this behavior? Is there any workaround I can try to make the Reflections library work when invoked as part of a unit test run by Maven ?

Comment: URL's in HashSet? I'm being reminded of this Java puzzle: http://javaantipatterns.wordpress.com/2007/11/24/comparing-urls-with-urlequals/

Comment: Interesting link @Rekin, but in any case it is possible to put those urls in a set without problem, maybe because they are pointing to local jars and directories (?) not sure... (I did not write that code, just took it from the Reflections google library). Just out of curiosity, if you know why it is working (apparently contradicting your link) please let me know!.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably using M2Eclipse, which adds stuff to the classpath on its own. Command-line Maven works differently. You might find [some options that will help](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/class-loading.html).

Comment: Looks like the surefire plugin surely did not fire.

Comment: Have just tried with command line Maven with the same results

Comment: +1 thanks for the link @user237815. I think I prefer my solution of finding the effective classpaths however, since in this way my library will work with classpaths declared in manifest files also (I discovered it was not working in those situations "thanks" to this problem with Maven), but I am happily accepting your answer since I did not know the options mentioned in the link!.

Answer (score 7):

Solved it. Posting the solution in case someone find the same problem in the future.

When executing the unit tests of a project, Maven does not (explicitly) include in the classpath all its dependencies.
Instead, it declares a dependency on a tmp jar located in "target/surefire/surefirebooter_NUMBER_THAT_LOOKS_LIKE_TIME_STAMP.jar".
This jar only contains a manifest file that declares a classpath for the project.

The method `forClassLoader` in the Reflections library does not return a set of urls with the **effective** classpath (i.e., classpath entries in manifest files are ignored).
To overcome this, I just implemented this simple method:

```
public static Set<URL> effectiveClassPathUrls(ClassLoader... classLoaders) {
    return ClasspathHelper.forManifest(ClasspathHelper.forClassLoader(classLoaders));
}
```

The method `forManifest` (also part of the Reflections library) adds to the set of classpath urls sent as parameter, the missing classpath entries declared in manifest files of any jar  files contained in the set. In this way the method returns a set of URLs with the effective classpath of the project.

Comment: Right, or you could try my solution. Look at the link. Try adding useManifestOnlyJar=false and useSystemClassLoader=true in the surefire plugin.

Comment: @ccleve, it seems this has helped. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem. Adding following URL did the trick for me.

```
ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
cb.setUrls(...);
cb.addUrls(YourClassName.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation());
```

Comment: This worked for me too. I have a URLClassLoader in production code that loads some JARs, so I keep track of the URLs and use them for Reflections, and for tests I just mock the method that retrieves the URLs and return what you've got here.

The classpath of the application I'm working on is absolutely giant, and explicitly specifying the URLs to scan reduced the scan time from around 5 seconds to 80 milliseconds.

Answer (score 2):

I just encountered the same problem with Reflections library (version 0.9.11), only when executing unit tests from Maven builds. The link provided in the accepted answer pointed me in the right direction.

A simple POM file change to my Surefire plugin fixed this:

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.21.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.21.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

The `<useSystemClassLoader>` config parameter defaults to 'true'. Forcing it to 'false' seems to resolve the classloader problem in my unit tests.

Comment: This is perfect, codeless solution! I haven't encountered any downside to setting useSystemClassLoader to false

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues you can create that makes surefire fail.

1. there is a naming convention; test suites should be called 'TestBlaBla' or 'BlaBlaTest'; beginning or ending with the word 'Test'.
2. as mentioned earlier, the classpath in Maven is more restricted than it is in Eclipse as Eclipse (stupidly) does not separate the compile classpath from the test classpath.
3. Surefire is free to run test cases from different test suites in any order. When running multiple test suites that initialize some common base (such as an in-memory database or a JNDI context) that can create conflicts where test suites start to influence each other. You need to take care to properly isolate test suites. Tricks I use are to use separate in-memory databases for suites, and I initialize shared things per unit test in stead of per test suite.

3 is the hardest to debug I can tell you; whenever something works in Eclipse and not in Maven I naturally assume I'm doing something wrong in isolating the test suite.

Comment: Hi @Gimby. I am following the naming conventions and my simple tests do not have any race condition so it does not matter if they are executed in any order. I think it is something related to class loading in maven but still I cannot find out what the problem exactly is.