# Google Reflections & Maven - not finding data in Maven but works in IDE

Tags: maven, maven-3, reflections

## Problem

Simple process request:  **find all extensions of `List.class` in the `java.util` package**.

Here is the source I am using:

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections("java.util");
Set<Class<?>> subtypes = reflections.getSubTypesOf(List.class);
```

Pretty simple, right?

It works in both IntelliJ IDEA and in Eclipse, but is not working when I run my tests via Maven.  I tried adding things using the `org.reflections.util.ConfigurationBuilder`'s provided methods for adding URLs and filtering on package names with no luck.

Any suggestions?

I looked through this post but was not able to get things working:  "[Unit test using the Reflections google library fails only when executed by Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13576665/unit-test-using-the-reflections-google-library-fails-only-when-executed-by-maven)"

## Code

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>ohno</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.reflections</groupId>
      <artifactId>reflections</artifactId>
      <version>0.9.10</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
      <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
      <version>6.9.10</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

**Sample.java**

```
package com.example.uhoh;

import org.reflections.Reflections;
import java.util.Set;

public class Sample {

  @SuppressWarnings ("unchecked")
  public static Set<Class<?>> lookup(Class<?> type) {
    Reflections reflections = new Reflections("java.util");
    return (Set<Class<?>>) reflections.getSubTypesOf(type);
  }
}
```

**SampleTest.java**

```
package com.example.uhoh;

import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

@Test
public class SampleTest {

  public void testSample() {
    Set<Class<?>> result = Sample.lookup(List.class);
    Assert.assertNotNull(result, "NULL returned.");
    Assert.assertFalse(result.isEmpty(), "Unable to find any extensions of java.util.List");
  }
}
```

## Output

**Working in IDE**
[image: Sample Working in IDE]

**Maven Output**

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.example.uhoh.SampleTest
Configuring TestNG with: org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.conf.TestNG652Configurator@4e515669
Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.261 sec <<< FAILURE!
(com.example.uhoh.SampleTest)  Time elapsed: 0.071 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError: Unable to find any extensions of java.util.List expected [false] but found [true]
    at org.testng.Assert.fail(Assert.java:94)
    at org.testng.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:513)
    at org.testng.Assert.assertFalse(Assert.java:63)
    at com.example.uhoh.SampleTest.testSample(SampleTest.java:15)


Results :

Failed tests:   (com.example.uhoh.SampleTest): Unable to find any extensions of java.util.List expected [false] but found [true]

Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

## Parallel Error

**Code**
    public void testSample() {
      Class[] dataTypes = {
        ArrayList.class, LinkedList.class,
        List.class, AbstractList.class,
        Collection.class,
        Map.class, Properties.class
      };

```
  Arrays.stream(dataTypes).parallel().forEach(next -> {
    Set<Class<?>> result = Sample.lookup(next);
    Assert.assertNotNull(result, "NULL returned.");
    Assert.assertFalse(result.isEmpty(), "Unable to find any extensions of java.util.List");
  });
}
```

**Maven Output**

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: zip file closed`

Comment: I will put some together.

Comment: I added a sample here that reproduces the issue.  It's an extremely simple means to reproduce it and it should be enough to let anyone see what is going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix your issue, use Reflections' `ConfigurationBuilder` to manually set the URL for the jar that contains the class.  This works in IntelliJ, and when invoking the Surefire plugin using command line Maven, `mvn test`.

**Sample.java**

```
public static Set<Class<?>> lookup(Class<?> type) {
    ConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();

    // For List.class, this will be a path to rt.jar.
    configurationBuilder.addUrls(ClasspathHelper.forClass(type));

    Reflections reflections = new Reflections(configurationBuilder);
    return (Set<Class<?>>) reflections.getSubTypesOf(type);
}
```

Comment: Using a parallel stream to test this, I get “_java.lang.IllegalStateException: zip file closed_”.  The code I used is added above - removing `parallel()` works.  What you provided is most certainly the answer to the root problem.

Answer (score 7):

I just encountered the same problem with Reflections library (version 0.9.11), only when executing unit tests from Maven builds. A simple POM file change to my Surefire plugin fixed this for me.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.21.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.21.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

The `<useSystemClassLoader>` config parameter defaults to 'true'. Forcing it to 'false' seems to resolve the classloader problem in my unit tests.